# Can't get last errors from COM Object in C#

Tags: c#, activexobject, comobject

My `C#` code:

```
bvt = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("xxx.BVT"));

// calling a function that terminates with an error
bvt.GiveMeAnError();

var msg = "";
long number = 0L;
bvt.GetLastError(number, msg);

result = "Errornumber:"+ number + " Errormessage:"+ msg;
```

The result is:

> "Errornumber:0 Errormessage:"

My problem is the function `GetLastError()`. `Number` and `msg` should contain the `errornumber` and `message` after execution of this function. But they are still `empty`.

Can somebody help me?

*** EDIT ***

I executed the following code as VBScript:

```
Dim StdOut
Set StdOut = WScript.StdOut
Set bvt = CreateObject( "xxx.BVT" )

bvt.GiveMeAnError()

bIsLastErr = bvt.GetLastError( ErrNo, ErrMsg )
StdOut.WriteLine( "Erronumber: " & ErrNo & ", Errormessage: " & ErrMsg )
```

This VBScript with cscript is working fine. I also get the errormessage and number. So the GetLastError() Method works.

Comment: You just instantiated your object, without calling any of its members . Why it should already have an error ?

Comment: post the method `GetLastError`

Comment: Hey nlips, sorry I forgot. I call a function after the instantiation of my object. This function is (definitely) terminated with an error.

Comment: well you've assigned it them to being an empty string and 0, either you'll find them on the bvt object or you'll need to make references.

Comment: I think I mistook the question. What is it actually `GetLastError()`?

Comment: @Shaharyar - I have only a description of the method GetLastError, sorry no access to this Method. Its on the device. 
The description: "Used to retrieve specific error Information (error number, error message) from the very last used BVT Service function all"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the variables by reference as they're apparently set in the method:

```
bvt.GetLastError(ref number, ref msg);
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you CodeCaster!

The problem was "var" and "long". And of course you have to pass the variables by reference. Here is my working code:

```
object number = null;
object msg = null;

// ... do some stuff with Errors ...

bvt.GetLastError(ref number, ref msg);

return "" + number.ToString() +" - " + msg.ToString() + "\n";
```